# what plastic is used in the floatable hull of 60266 Ocean Exploration ship?

Tags: repair, plastics, glue, set-modification

I need to know what plastic is used for the hull (dark blue) of the [60266: Ocean Exploration Ship](https://brickset.com/sets/60266-1/Ocean-Exploration-Ship), in order to glue a reinforcement on.

I bought this for my boys (younger than the advertised 7+).  It is a *really* fantastic playable model.  Expensive per-part, put the floating ship and crane (on a gantry! :) ) is great.  However, the hull is two sections (one bow, one stern) - and this is a problem.

Inexplicably, Lego did not devise a way to robustly connect the two halfs.  they are connected only by studs at the top.  So even with care, the studs work their way loose - and to borrow from SpaceX - **RUD** !
[image]

I would like to find a way to glue on a re-enforcement on the lower levels of the hull, preferably from Technic.  However the plastic has a different feel, and seems a different stiffness - so I'm not sure if it's the standard ABS as the rest of the parts??

[image: 60266: Ocean Exploration Ship]

Comment: I think, dark blue part element could be made of polyethylene, but don't take this as an answer. Just a suggestion. There is some space/volume inside the hull after placing the top cover. This allows you to experiment and find a glue that works best.

Comment: OP's using [the Kragle](https://evil.fandom.com/wiki/Kragle)!

Comment: I am not 100% sure but I could imagine parts such as these are creating using [vacuum forming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_forming). I know that is how the [old CITY road plates were made](https://www.newelementary.com/2021/05/lego-city-interview-road-plates.html) which is why they could not be used to connect bricks underneath. That might explain the lack of stiffness but perhaps that could narrow down the plastic used.

Comment: I got red colored copy of the hull. By touch it has different feeling than the usual baseplate, which is a bit stiffer and its surface is harder than of the hull. Oh and I found my copy has PIP at the bottom.

Comment: pretty sure the hull is molded, not vacuum formed.  both sides are form faced, and have mold markings.